# Making my first webpage, how to remove .html from the page address?

Tags: html

I am working on my first web page and am developing it using c9.io as my development environment (good for working with teams on small stuff).

I am trying to achieve navigation in my site by linking to different html pages (a help page).

I was trying to have a contact page by having

> mysite.com/help

and I have a HTML page called

> help.html.

Trying to navigate to my site I see I cannot access mysite.com/help but instead I can navigate to mysite.com/help.html.

At least in c9 removing the .html in the name makes it not recognize as a HTML file, but is that the solution I need or there something else going on?

Thanks

Comment: you should search for "pretty urls"

Comment: Which environment are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this is with a file called `.htaccess` (with the starting dot)

You can write the next code and will remove the html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^help(.*)$ help.html
```

You can add as many pages you need here

Comment: not so sure that this environment supports htacces... (that is based on apache in other words)

Comment: @LelioFaieta I just check cloud9 and It seems to have apache, just depends on what pipeline installs

Comment: What do I need to install?

Comment: @Pipeline is cloud 9 which environment do you install? only HTML5? or PHP? Wordpress? etc..

Answer (score 0):

Make `.htaccess` file and paste this code. This will remove the `.html` extension in the url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: not so sure that this environment supports htacces... (that is based on apache in other words)